# How can i add so much darkness in an image?

Tags: image, graphics, photoshop, gimp

I have downloaded this image from pexels and i want to create similar effect on my photo but i cant find the desired method over internet. I want to add darkness or shadow downside. How can do it through gimp or adobe photoshop cs3?

[image: image with dark surrounding male face wearing red hat]

Comment: Really a question for the [GraphicsDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Furthermore this may be an unedited photo. You can do this kind of things with a very focused lighting (google "Snoot flash")([example](https://www.diyphotography.net/diy-homemade-speedlite-snoot/)).

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has a spotlight effect that can do that, even in **CS3**. 
 You can go to `Filter -> Render -> Light Effects` and choose `Spot` from the drop down menu.

[This video](https://layersmagazine.com/photoshop-photography-lighting.html) has a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

First of You go to on `Selective Color` and than if you can anything on image.

[image]